# "Artificial" vs. "faux" vs. "fake"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, adjectives

Do these words have a different meaning?

Should we say *artificial sugar* or *sweetener*? Should we say *artificial fur* or *faux fur*?

Is there a rule that defines the border for *artificial/faux/fake*?

Comment: Those words are **not** synonyms. They are **not** interchangeable at all times. Please see definitions within each relevant domain. *Faux fur*; *artificial (synthetic) sweetener*; *fake Picasso*.

Comment: @Kris: Synonyms are words that are interchangeable _on occasion_ (otherwise there wouldn't be any).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Who said no? Why else would I waste efforts in writing **two** distinct sentences? And while at it, may I ask the comment's up voter, what really they understand about these two comments? :)

Comment: @Kris: It looks like your two sentences are appositive. An 'And certainly' would disambiguate.

Answer (score 3):

[AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/faux) treats them as synonyms:

> faux (foʊ)
>
> adj. artificial or imitation; fake: *faux pearls*.

However, they are very rarely interchangeable, as Kris points out.

**Faux** has the connotation of 'accurate (more or less) representation / imitation with no moral intention to deceive'; it is a rather 'fancy' term (probably due to the obvious French derivation) useful to advertisers:

> When manufacturing faux objects or materials, an attempt is often made
>   to create products which will resemble the imitated items as closely
>   as possible. However, some products are intentionally made to look
>   "faux", for example, faux furs made for prospective buyers who want
>   their fur to be recognizable as imitation due to controversy over the
>   use and manufacture of real animal furs. [Wikipedia]

**Artificial** is the 'unmarked' term (artificial limb; artificial intelligence; artificial sweetner; artificial light) but can connote a lacking of a desirable quality ((of a person or a person's behavior) insincere or affected [Google]).

**Fake** has shady / tacky connotations (a fake Rembrandt; a fake gun).

Comment: Though note, the oddity in the definitions of *natural flavor* and *artificial flavor* where the latter refers to flavors that have not been discovered in nature whereas the former includes synthetic instances so long as they match the chemical in the natural flavor.

Comment: +1 and another thing to note is that *artificial* can be modified using *very, somewhat, really, rather, quite*, etc., while *faux* cannot. *Fake* is somewhere in-between. I think that goes to further show the unmarkedness of *artificial* vs. the other two.

Comment: Surprised that no one mentioned that *artificial* is the antonym of *natural*. That's the the natural meaning of *artificial*, all other senses are contrived.

Comment: It should perhaps be noted that, as a matter or pragmatics, *faux* is rarely used outside the contexts that have to do with fashion and design, even if using it would fit the definition.